# Mostrar texto ao passar mouse no autocomplete

Tags: primefaces

Tenho o seguinte autocomplete:

```
<p:autoComplete id="meuId"
            label="#{messages['mesage']}:"
            completeMethod="#{metodo}" var="bean"
            itemValue="#{bean.id}" itemLabel="#{bean.descritivo}" dropdown="true"
            converter="xx"
            required="false">
```

Como eu faço pra que ao passar o mouse por cima do componente seja exibido uma mensagem informativa ?

Comment: Você pode fazer tanto com Javascript assim https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ ou com css http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_hover

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar o [Tooltip](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml) do Primefaces:

```
<p:autoComplete id="meuId"
        label="#{messages['mesage']}:"
        completeMethod="#{metodo}" var="bean"
        itemValue="#{bean.id}"
        itemLabel="#{bean.descritivo}"
        dropdown="true"
        converter="xx"
        required="false" />
<p:tooltip id="tipMeuId" for="meuId" value="Mensagem a exibir" position="top"/>
```

É super simples de usar e possui várias opções de customização